# My p5.js canvas window continues to change with each code execution. How can I stop this?

Tags: javascript, windows, p5.js

I just downloaded the p5.js editor earlier today and I've been playing around with it mostly for fun. However I've noticed that when using createCanvas(), the only time the resulting window is the correct size is the first time I execute the code. Every subsequent time, the window height decreases by a small amount, and the window width increases by a similar amount.

Below is my code:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(4);
  stroke(255);

  //Create rows of circles with a thick white outline across the entirety of the canvas
  //Their x and y values are used to create some static random variation in color (r, g, b)
  for (var y = 0; y <= height; y += 50) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += 50) {
      fill(x%255, (x*y)%255, y%255);
      ellipse(x, y, 25, 25);
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is what the window looks like after the code's first execution.](https://puu.sh/pjHKH/f82949b8a0.jpg) The dimensions of the window match the dimensions of the canvas perfectly.

[Here is what the window looks like after closing and executing the code 3 times.](https://puu.sh/pjHNz/e7549e024c.jpg) This deformation of the window continues in this way until literally only the title bar is left.

The problem persists even while using createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight)

I have the latest build of the p5.js editor for Windows (currently 0.5.10), and I am running on Windows 10. I cannot find any reports of other users with this issue, so I feel kind of stuck. It's not a huge issue but it's just inconvenient enough to be annoying.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @e4en This question is about a specific editor, so providing a fiddle defeats the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug. I've filed a bug report [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-editor/issues/241). Feel free to add any details I left out.

The [editor download page](https://p5js.org/download/) says this:

> The p5.js editor is currently in development, try out a beta version
>   of it now. Help out by posting [feedback and
>   bugs](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-editor/issues).

For now you could go to settings (the little gear icon in the upper-right corner of the editor) and change the "Run in browser" setting to "On". That will cause your sketches to launch in your browser instead of in the popup window.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for putting in a bug report! I wasn't certain if it wad a bug or if I had messed up some sort of setting, perhaps in the html file. I can live with it being a bug for now, though. Thanks again!

Comment: @Taiyou No problem. Note that you can mark an answer as correct if it helped you out! :p